# Error loading target specification: Could not find specification for target

Tags: rust, linker-errors, rlib

I'm following [this tutorial](https://os.phil-opp.com/set-up-rust/) on how to make an EXTREMELY BASIC Operating System in Rust. This is my current state:

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "blog_os"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Philipp Oppermann <dev@phil-opp.com>"]   # Here I used my own details

[lib]
crate-type = ["staticlib"]
```

**src/lib.rs**

```
#![feature(lang_items)]
#![no_std]

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn rust_main() {}

#[lang = "eh_personality"] extern fn eh_personality() {}
#[lang = "panic_fmt"] #[no_mangle] pub extern fn panic_fmt() -> ! {loop{}}
```

**x86_64-blog_os.json**

```
{
  "llvm-target": "x86_64-unknown-none",
  "data-layout": "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128",
  "linker-flavor": "gcc",
  "target-endian": "little",
  "target-pointer-width": "64",
  "target-c-int-width": "32",
  "arch": "x86_64",
  "os": "none",
  "disable-redzone": true,
  "features": "-mmx,-sse,+soft-float"
}
```

Here is the [Makefile](https://github.com/phil-opp/blog_os/blob/post_3/Makefile).

---

If you scroll down to the **Fixing Linker Errors** section in the tutorial, we're basically asked to add the following lines to our `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
rlibc = "1.0"
```

Then specify the external crate in `lib.rs` (after the `#![no_std]`):

```
extern crate rlibc;
```

When I run `make run` in the terminal, I get the following error message:

```
error: Error loading specification: Could not find specification for target "x86_64-blog_os" 

error: Could not compile 'rlibc'
```

We're expected to get an error... just not this one. The example in the **Fixing Linker Errors** section gives an idea of the kind of error we should expect.

What may be going wrong? I've searched everywhere on Google with no solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. These issues on Xargo and Cargo seem to suggest there's a bug about the location of target specs:

- https://github.com/japaric/xargo/issues/44
- https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4865

Setting `RUST_TARGET_PATH=pwd` before invoking `xargo` fixed the issue for me. The invocation in the given Makefile will then look like this:

```
@RUST_TARGET_PATH=$(shell pwd) xargo build --target $(target)
```

Comment: Thanks a billion. Worked like a charm, literally been looking on Google for the past 3 days haha